# Regular expression ignoring dash or hyphen at the middle of text

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out how I can ignore the hyphen or dash as seen below

```
chug-jug
```

`/chugjug/i` should match with chug-jug. Thank you!

Some other examples include:

`I-no` match with `/ino/i`

`Jack-O` match with `/jacko/i`

Comment: `-?` 0 or more dashes

Comment: @mplungjan i think i jus wanna ignore the dash in the between the strings.

Comment: oh i see that you are using a quantifier, i will go read the documentation and test it out in my code. because i also want to escape the space as well! Thank you!

Comment: Escape the space? What is the complete use-case here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for the `i-no` case:

```
/i-?n-?o-?/i
```

Explanation:

- `-?` means zero or one dash
- we have to add it after each letter. Without this the pattern would be `/ino/i`
- The trailing `/i` means case insensitive

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Tl8CAy/1).

Alternative solution: remove the dashes with replace.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) ignoring hyphens can be easily achieved by removing them before matching the string against your current regex.

```
"chug-jug"
  .replace(/-/g, "") // remove all hyphens from the string
  .match(/chugjug/i) // match the string against your regex
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like this :

```
/c[^chugjug]*?h[^chugjug]*?u[^chugjug]*?g[^chugjug]*?j[^chugjug]*?u[^chugjug]*?g[^chugjug]*?/g
```

demo here : https://regex101.com/r/wU6izW/1

Comment: Hello, i think your solution might work, lemme some looks at it. Thank you so much!

Comment: With this you can check for the word even if the dashes appear anywhere in the string

Comment: can't it be like `/([chugjug][^chugjug]*?)+/g` ?

Comment: I never said this is the only way or solution, you are free to post your answer

Comment: @HarshitRastogi your answer is what i wanted haha, i wanted to be able to find the character regardless of where the hyphen is. Thanks

Comment: @GhostOps damn i think your answer works as well, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @tanshiyu i just shrunk the regex as much as i can...

Comment: @GhostOps's comment matches characters in any order, not only the word!

Comment: `[^chugjug]*?` does not only match hyphens but anything that is not `c`, `h`, `u`, `g`, `j`, `u` or `g`. Here `chugQjug` would also match because `Q` is not in `[chugjug]`.